# what is this type pulses called?

Tags: signal, frequency, pulse, modulation

I was wondering what is this type of pulses is call. Is it a sin wave? I know its the result of sinusoidal pulse modulation. is it considerd a quasi-sin wave?

I would like to know the name to research it more.
[image]

Comment: It depends on the context. Where did you find it?

Comment: it is from a doppler radar sensor (recieved). Currently, I am using the sensor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this pattern is called "wave packet".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet

Answer (score 2):

It's called a 'wavelet'. Google for that.

Comment: And Bing Images it.